Numerically compute the volume of an implicit submanifold
Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to N$ be a smooth function and $M=f^{-1}(p)$ be the preimage of a regular value (more generally we could have the preimage of a submanifold transverse to $f$) and we can assume $M$ is compact, oriented, and whichever mild properties that can make the question easier. The usual way to obtain the volume of $M$ is using the implicit function theorem to obtain charts for $M$ and compute an integral involving them. However, in general there is no closed form for these charts and they can be difficult or inconvenient to compute.
For codimension $1$ manifolds, if we have say $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ and $M=f^{-1}(r)$ and $f^{-1}([0,r])$ is compact and contained in a box $B$ and its boundary is $M$, we can use Stokes's theorem
$$\int_{M}S=\int_{f^{-1}([0,r])}dS$$
where $S$ is the area element, and we have
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{h=1}^n \frac{\partial_h f}{|\nabla f|}dx_1\dots\hat{dx_i}\dots dx_n\\
dS &=\left(\frac{\Delta f}{|\nabla f|}-\sum_{h=1}^n\frac{\partial_h f\partial_h |\nabla f|}{|\nabla f|^2}\right)dx_1\dots dx_n.
\end{align}
And then do Monte-Carlo integration i.e. sample points $x$ uniformly in the box, check if they satisfy $f(x)<r$ and average $dS$ over them (otherwise discarded) then divide by the volume of $f^{-1}([0,r])$ which we naturally obtain as the volume of the box times the proportion of points not discarded. Note that this can all be done computing only $f$, and no charts.
Is there some similar method for higher codimension?
